# Unable to make progress running work - Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Android Studio Iguana | In the 2023.2.1 Canary 7 version, this error occurs at the end of the build.

For example, it can be verified that this is happening in the Now Android project created by Google.

[Project](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/)

The relevant bug has been fixed in previous versions, but it continues in experimental versions.

[Issue Link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/290954881)

The Error Message

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Unable to make progress running work. There are items queued for execution but none of them can be started
```

Is there a known solution?

Comment: Some one has narrowed down the issue and a workaround. And for those who stumble here, please do upvote (+1 on the top) in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/328871352